# onClick only firing on <i>-element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div covering the whole page with an onClick bound to it. It has position: absolute and registers all clicks on the page. If e.target isn't holding a certain node, I don't do anything with that.

This seems to block other onClick events on other divs, which is logical I guess. The thing I don't understand is that i-elements in the smaller divs still have the onClick working.

How come the onClick isn't blocked on the i-elements aswell?

Related question: Can I make all the divs clickable? So that the onClick function fires on both the larger div aswell as the smaller divs beneath it?

Edit: There really isn't much more to it than what I displayed. Will try and make it a little more clear, but basically this is it. Might add 
Don't know about an online tool that can provide a working example when it comes to React.

React:

```
checkForClick(e) {
 const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.someNode);
 if (node && !e.target.contains(node)) {
  this.setState({something: false});
 }
}


render()  {
 return (
  <div className='click-trigger' onClick={(e) => this._checkForClick(e)}></div>
   <div onClick={this._otherFunction}>
    // This content doesn't fire _otherFunction
    Content
    // The <i> fires _otherFunction
    <i className='fas fa-circle' />
  </div>
 )
}
```

CSS:

```
.click-trigger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You need to give a better example, this is hard to decypher. If you have a div overlaying everything, it wont let you click under, no matter what.

Comment: I think he means the div is wrapping everything, but yeah setup a working example.

Comment: Your code should work... I tested similar  code here https://codesandbox.io/s/o5mlymrvj9?fontsize=14

Comment: I'll keep debugging... can't replicate the problem. In this example the 'Icon' should be clickable: https://codesandbox.io/s/k0vrlm7ppo?fontsize=14

I do however appreciate advice on how to make both the here and there functions to firein my example. (there only when the smaller div is clicked of course)